# How to serve .pcss files in Meteor.js app?

Tags: meteor, postcss

I have a postcss enabled in my app, but I want to keep things separated. So how I can make Meteor to support css as .css and postcss as .pcss.

Comment: DId you use a Meteor package or NPM package for post css?